# Uninstall CURL from Mac

Tags: macos, curl

Can someone tell me how can I uninstall CURL from Mac ?.

I have deleted the folder containing curl from Mac.

But after deleting the folder also when I run "curl -V" it shows the current version of curl along with the available protocols as seen below.

[image]

This makes me to suspect that the curl may not have been uninstalled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`curl` comes with the OS. I am not sure why you would want to uninstall it but it is most likely a horrible idea as the system may depend on it.

If you had installed another version of curl (which you now removed) you can check which curl is now being called by doing a `which curl`. What's the output of this command?

It should be `/usr/bin/curl` which is what the system comes with.

In case you installed it via *homebrew*, you should always uninstall via `brew uninstall curl`. You can try issuing that command now to clean up.